# perl script to connect two databases at same time

Tags: mysql, database, perl

I am trying to connect to 2 databases on the same instance of MySQL from 1 Perl script.

I am using this in a migration script where I am grabbing data from the original database and inserting it into the new one.

Connecting to 1 database and then trying to initiate a second connection with the same user just changes the current database to the new one.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use strict;

my $driver = "mysql";
my $database1 = "db1";
my $dsn1 = "DBI:$driver:database=$database1";
my $userid = "userhead";
my $password = "pwdhead";
my $database2 = "db2";
my $dsn2 = "DBI:$driver:database=$database2";

my $dbh1 = DBI->connect($dsn1, $userid, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;
my $dbh2 = DBI->connect($dsn2, $userid, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $sth = $dbh2->prepare("INSERT INTO Persons") $dbh1->prepare("SELECT *FROM Persons");
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
print "Number of rows found :" + $sth->rows;
```

In the above example i am trying to copy from one database table to another datbase table. but i am getting error while running the script. Please help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to multiple databases in a perl script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607249/connecting-to-multiple-databases-in-a-perl-script)

Comment: "i am getting error while running the script" For future reference, it's always helpful to include those error messages in your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At a guess, you're trying to use the same database handle to connect to both databases. If you need to operate two separate connections then you need two separate handles

This program uses the `data_sources` class method to discover all of the available MySQL databases and creates a connection to each of them, putting the handles in the array `@dbh`. You can use each element of that array as normal, for instance

```
my $stmt = $dbh[0]->prepare('SELECT * FROM table)
```

It may be that you prefer to set up the `@databases` array manually, or the username and password may be different for the two data sources, so some variation on this may be necessary

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use DBI;

my $user = 'username';
my $pass = 'password';

my @databases = DBI->data_sources('mysql');

my @dbh = map { DBI->connect($_, $user, $pass) } @databases;
```

---

#### Update

You need to *select* data from the source table, *fetch* it one row at a time, and *insert* each row into the destination table

Here's an idea how that might work, but you need to adjust the number of question marks in the `VALUES` of the `INSERT` statement to match the number of columns

Note that, if you're just intending to copy the whole dataset, there aree better ways to go about this. In particular, if you have any foreign key constraints then you won't be able to add data until the table it it is dependent on is populated

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use DBI;

my $userid   = "userhead";
my $password = "pwdhead";

my ($dbase1, $dbase2) = qw/ db1 db2 /;

my $dsn1 = "DBI:mysql:database=$dbase1";
my $dsn2 = "DBI:mysql:database=$dbase2";

my $dbh1 = DBI->connect($dsn1, $userid, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;
my $dbh2 = DBI->connect($dsn2, $userid, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $select = $dbh1->prepare("SELECT * FROM Persons");
my $insert = $dbh2->prepare("INSERT INTO Persons VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$select->execute;
while ( my @row = $select->fetchrow_array ) {
    $insert->execute(@row);
}
```

If you need to handle the columns from the source data separately then you can use named scalars instead of the array `@row`. Like this

```
while ( my ($id, $name) = $select->fetchrow_array ) {
    my $lastname = '';
    $insert->execute($id, $name, $lastname);
}
```

Comment: Please check the edited question. I am trying to copy the data from one datbase table to another database table. but i dont know how to join the statements in perl script

Comment: @ashu: Okay, I've added an update to my solution. You can't ***"join the statements in the Perl script"*** — you simply have to read the data from one table and then insert it into the other

Comment: @ashu: Well I can't tell you how to generate data for the `lastname` column, but the array `@row` contains the values for all columns from `db1`. You can use named scalar variables instead of an array as I have shown in my solution

Answer (score 1):

Plan A (especially if one-time task):

Run `mysqldump` on the source machine; feed the output to `mysql` on the target machine.  This will be much faster and simpler.  If you are on a Unix machine, do it with an `exec()` from Perl (if you like).

Plan B (especially if repeated task):

If the table is not "too big", do one `SELECT` to fetch all the rows into an array in Perl.  Then `INSERT` the rows into the target machine.  This can be sped up (with some effort) if you build a multi-row `INSERT` or create a CSV file and use `LOAD DATA` instead of `INSERT`.